# How does Hugo's Related Content algorithm work? What are the factors?

Tags: algorithm, go, static, recommendation-engine, hugo

On their website they say:

> Hugo uses a set of factors to identify a page’s related content based on Front Matter parameters. This can be tuned to the desired set of indices and parameters or left to Hugo’s default Related Content configuration.

[Source](https://gohugo.io/content-management/related/#:%7E:text=Hugo%20uses%20a%20set%20of,Hugo%27s%20default%20Related%20Content%20configuration.)

But how exactly does the algorithmus work? What are the factors?

Comment: You can dive into the source [here](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/related/inverted_index.go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original approach is explained in [`gohugoio/hugo` PR 3815](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/pull/3815)

> Several attempts have been started to fix [#98](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/98) -- all of them have failed for some reason.
> It is a hard problem to solve, and I think the main reason for failure has been the bottom-up-approach, i.e. we have started with the hardest problem: [Solving Sherlock's last case](https://github.com/joearms/sherlock).
>
> The reason I'm picking up this ball again now is [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/scott_lowe/status/898398437527363585):
>
> Using intersect and keywords in page params work reasonably well, but it is quadratic and will be slow to unusable for larger sites.
>
> So, instead of solving the hardest problem, I have started on this PR by outlining an interface:
>
> ```golang
> type PageSearcher interface {
>   Search(args ...interface{}) (Pages, error)
>   SearchIndex(index string, args ...interface{}) (Pages, error)
>   Similar(p *Page) (Pages, error)
>   SimilarIndex(index string, p *Page) (Pages, error)
> }
> ```
>
> Naming suggestions welcomed.
>
> The idea is that a user defines a set of indexes in config.toml:
>
> ```
> indexes:
>  - param: keywords
>    weight: 1
> - param: tags
>    weight: 3
> ```
>
> Then we lazily build some sort of index from that, and then you can do fast searches like:
>
> ```golang
> {{ .Site.RegularPages.Similar . }}
> {{ .Site.RegularPages.Search "hugo" }}
> {{ .Site.RegularPages.SearchIndex "keywords" "hugo" | limit 10 }}
> ```

Initial implementation: [gohugoio/hugo commit 3b4f17b](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commit/3b4f17bbc9ff789faa581ac278ad109d1ac5b816)